# How can i parse html by jsoup on website that's protected by cloudflare

Tags: java, jsoup

***Code is:***

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.xxxxx.com/") //Website using cloudflare
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36")
                .followRedirects(true)
                .get();
        System.out.println(doc);
```

**result**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=https://xxxxx.com
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
    at model.test2.main(test2.java:23)
Java Result: 1
```

**How can i parse html by jsoup on website that's protected by cloudflare.**

Comment: I don't think this is a JSoup or CloudFlare problem, but rather a problem with the specific site you are trying to contact. I just used your code to fetch https://lenskit.org (which uses CloudFlare, albeit without the strongest protections) without problems.

Comment: Inspect a working GET with browser's developer tools and include all the headers you'll see, like Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language ...

Comment: why not just connect using other framework and then just pass the html to jsoup?